# Can I use Entangle for tethered shooting and only copy jpeg files to speed up transfers?

Tags: tethering, software-recommendation, linux

I'm currently trying to figure out if [Entangle](http://entangle-photo.org/), a Linux--based tethered shooting application, can be restricted to only copy files of a specific type.

My goal is to download only JPGs while shooting JPG+RAW (to an SD card). I just want a quick preview on a laptop/PC screen (a small resolution JPG is fine) but to retain the RAW for future editing on the camera SD card. The official Canon EOS utilities application can download only the JPGs and leave the RAWs in camera, but I can't find software for Linux capable of this.
Does anyone know of a solution to this, a similar program, some hack, or some other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Entangle doesn't seem to have any documentation, but it looks like it's based upon the CLI utility, [gphoto](http://gphoto.org/), which you could call directly so that you only copy the .JPG files. [There's a `--keep-raw` option](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-gphoto2-cli.html) that looks like it might work.

See also: http://www.giric.com/2013/03/tethered-shooting-with-gphoto2/

Comment: after looking into gphoto manual etc. it's imposible to reach mentioned behavior. --filename options is just renaming tool. gphoto in --tethered-capture mode download every files that camera creates. if someone want this, then he must alter/create source code;   sources: [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/gphoto/feature-requests/435/)  [link](http://gphoto-software.10949.n7.nabble.com/capture-tethered-getting-raw-files-td12683.html)

Comment: @ZtracenaExistence, those links are from 2013. If you read the [gphoto2 man page](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-gphoto2-cli.html) you'll see various options, including `--keep-raw`. It may also be possible to use `--get-thumbnail`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `--keep-raw` works fine with `--capture-image-and-download` (while PC is using instead of camera trigger) but in `--capture-tethered` it downloads the RAW, too, and deletes it after downloading.

Comment: This is an old thread, but seems like --keep-raw now works with --capture-tethered too.